# How to set proportional value in legend?

Tags: qgis, legend, value-list

I have a GIS table with traffic flows.
The thickness is proportional to the traffic value and I'd like to have a little legend with 3 links proportional to setted value (eg: link1 proportional to 100 vehicles, link2 proportional to 500 vehicles and link3 proportional to 1000 vehicles).
Any suggestions?
I tried to use the "Legend" but it only represents a coloured link with no thickness.
I am using QGIS 1.8 Lisboa on Win7.

Comment: I use "single symbol" and in advanced setting I set the tickness proportional to the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is not yet implemented in QGIS neither in the stable version (1.8) nor in the master (1.9). But you can use a small workaround to solve that.

- Start by duplicating your layer;
- In layer "1" use graduated style, choose the number of classes that you want to show in the legend and press classify;
- Edit both symbols, ranges and labels of your classes to mimic the layer "1" representation;

[image]

- For layer "2" represent it using single style with scale size field connected to your data in advanced settings (like you already did). This will achieve the desired effect in the map canvas.
- Keep both layer visible;

[image]

- Now, in map composer add a new legend;
- In legend Items remove layer 1 and edit the name of layer 2;
- uncheck the auto-update box;

[image]

- Close the map composer, go back to the map canvas and make layer "2" invisible;
- After this, your map will show the layer "1" representation, and layer "2" legend.

[image]

Alexandre Neto

PS: I used QGIS master in the screenshoots because I did not have the stable version installed. The menus are a bit different in 1.8 but I believe this method will work in both versions.

Comment: It seems a good way to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use QGIS 1.9 (2.0) - it has functionality that you need. You can set up '**data defined properties**' and if you have for a example a field with the width that needed - you assign width property of the style to this field. See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: does that create a usable legend yet?